# Title for VB.NET on final project

Tags: vb.net, vb6

Next semester is my final semester. I need some title suggestion for my final project, but I'm still learning VB 6.0 and VB.NET. Flash and JavaScript are my weak subjects T.T, so I need some help.

Comment: Maybe if you tell us what your project is about we can help you out with the title...?

Comment: Just do a library loan or airline booking system like everyone else?

Comment: felipe fiali : that why i'm still looking for title.

Comment: carnotaurus : library loan and airline booking system have people doing already .

Comment: what about a bus ticking system or a DVD rental system or a Hospital management system

Comment: sudantha:dvd rental system maybe i can do it, but how to do the hostipal management system?

Comment: zydeco : what mp3 store ? i cant catch what u mean .

Comment: @CKK9999 .Like Patient info Management. Assign Nurse,staff.. keep doctor records . if you are doing ticketing system i can personally assist u coz i have already done it

Comment: Sudantha: ticketing system is using the online ,that why i cant do it because i dint learn it be4. Hospital management system just record the all information only?

Comment: @CKK9999 Oh so you need an idea not just the title. I see...

Comment: @felipe fiali : yup ,you are right

Comment: Not really a good fit for Stack Overflow? Programmers is more suitable?

Answer (score 0):

Just so this question can have an answer:

Simple store for MP3 files: keeping records of MP3 files that are available to download, how much they cost per MP3 file, how many times they've been downloaded. That kind of thing.

Comment: OK, i will asking my lecturer for confirm can accept this kind of thing first.Thks for suggestion.